# Where should Blender Download to?

Tags: workflow

I am pretty new. About a month into this. Still learning so please excuse the noob question. I uninstalled it after my first animation. I thought it may be the reason for my Java problems. Not sure about that but that is fixed and I am back. I noticed this time when I installed it that it went into C://Program Files/Canon/Easy-WebPrint EX. That's my printer files. Is that normal? Do I move it out of there? Maybe that was the problem the first time. idk

Comment: no that is *not* the normal directory. If blender is working, then no you dont need to move it. I would recommend the zip just unzip, put it anywhere and run blender, no install required.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question about blender really, you can determine, and should know, where your files download to, it's a setting on your browser. Having said that, blender can be used two ways,

One is installing it using the msi file, in which case it makes  no difference where you downloaded the file to, because once you run the install file it will install to your programs folder. At that point you can safely erase the msi file.

If you choose not to install blender, use the .zip file. You just have to unzip (uncompress) the file and run the blender.exe program from the resulting folder. Just make sure that you don't download and use a temp file that might get erased next time you open the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it installs to where you choose to install it. But you can also download the zip-file and run that directly, without installing anything. So Blender would not cause Java-problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing download location with installation location, both are completely different and unrelated.

If your file downloaded to that printer folder is because you chose to save it there, or through inaction (you didn't select a proper folder and just pressed *Ok*) let the browser save it there. Depending on your browser, that folder may have been the last used to save the last download so the next time you used it defaulted to the last used directory.

After download you must unpack (for ZIP files) or install for (MSI files). Where you install this from is irrelevant, what matters is the folder you now install it to. The MSI file should by default install to the correct location wherever you run it from, whereas the ZIP file will be extracted to where you tell it to, if you just right click it and coose *Extract* it will stay right in that weird printer folder you mentioned so it may seem like non standard location.

Either way non of that should cause any trouble for Blender or Java, Blender doesn't use or interfere with Java and the folder you run it should be mostly irrelevant.